# Android Catch Events on Notification (Long Press)

Tags: android, android-notifications

The standard short click on a Notification fires the PendingIntent held in it.

***Is it possible to catch other events?***

The requirement is to catch a Long Press.

Comment: I would like an answer also.

Comment: I think it is not possible. I look forward to see the answer

Comment: erm, just saw that Sherif elKhatib wants to provide the anwer... well.. I claimed that its not possible, but please prove me wrong, I'd be happy if there is actually a solution I don't know of. :)

Answer (score 11):

Although you can create custom Notification-Views with [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) and [RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) you have no means to manipulate underlying click-behavior. The only options you have got is to change some parameters for a handfull of ViewTypes:

- **Buttons**: setOnClickPendingIntent() [to change button-intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)
- **TextViews**: setTextViewText() [textview-contents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setTextViewText%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- **RemoteViews**: addView() [sounds great but works only to insert nested RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#addView%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29)
- **ListViews**: setOnClickFillInIntent() [Apply  intents for ListViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickFillInIntent%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29)
- **ImageViews**: setImageViewBitmap() [change the picture for an ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewBitmap%28int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29)
- and a few more..

**So to answer your Question: No, with the most current Google API (api lvl 17 - 14.01.2013) you can not insert a onLongClickListener into any of the view-elements within a notification.**

**Why is this so?**

RemoteView is only a boiled down, simpler derivate of a View. It is not even related to View (RemoteView extends Object) therefore does not provide all the options you would have in a real View ([View.setOnLongClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener%28android.view.View.OnLongClickListener%29)) .

**What are RemoteViews?**:

> A RemoteView can be executed by another process with the same permissions as the 
>   original application(that is why they are called Remote Views). This
>   way widgets and notifications run with the permissions of its defining application.
>
> From ICS on, long press on a notification triggers the "App Info"
>   option, so you can see which app is sending it (useful to identify
>   spamming apps) Also, from JellyBean on, you have enriched
>   notifications that allow you to do many things, including more than one
>   action, probably you can solve your problem with that.
>
> Shalafi

If you want more insight I recommend these articles:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html especially chapter 3.2 where you can find more valuable information.
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Comment: A few remarks.

The RemoteViews are there for reasons of ownership and permissions. That views are created by the system, not by your app, and therefore they have more permissions. That's why its use is limited (and that is why they are called Remote Views)

From ICS on, long press on a notification triggers the "App Info" option, so you can see which app is sending it (useful to identify spamming apps)

Also, from JellyBean on, you have enriched notifications that allow you many things, including more than one action, probably you can solve your problem with that.

Comment: Thanks shalafi for the insights, that's why I love stack overflow :)

Comment: @Shalafi do you probably have some sources? I googled alot but unfortunately did not find anything precicely depicting the use of RemoteViews in general.

Comment: I remember reading that on an article about home screen widgets, which also uses RemoteViews. Don't have the link at hand, but will look into it.

Comment: Actually your first link in chapter 2.1 says something about it, turns out I got the idea of the permissions wrong, it is the other way around: A RemoteView can be executed by another process with the same permissions as the original application. This way the Widget runs with the permissions of its defining application.

Comment: okay I changed the quote a little, though its no quote anymore hope you dont mind me just mashing up your statements ;D

Comment: no problem, it enriches the answer, so its fine :) Feel free to remove the quotes

Answer (score 1):

Just like an app-widget, it's a remote view, it only supports tap and vertical drag gesture